# Use button to move to next scroll-snap

Tags: reactjs

I have a next button in the sliding animation here. I want users to move to the next slide on clicking the next button and it ends on the last slide.

I'm quite new to programming so i tried the below approach to move to a specific div id but not working

<a href={`"#slide-${i+2}"`}

I'm doing this in react, but for simplicity, i have written this in simple form. Could someone help me with this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  
  
  
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  
  /*
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  */
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
.slides > div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.slides > div:target {
/*   transform: scale(0.8); */
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider > a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}
.slider > a:active {
  top: 1px;
}
.slider > a:focus {
  background: #000;
}

/* Don't need button navigation */
@supports (scroll-snap-type) {
  .slider > a {
    display: none;
  }
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74ABE2, #5563DE);
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <button>Next</button>
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div id="slide-5">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: uhhh this isn't react? this is vanilla javascript, html and css. Do you want your answer to be react?

Comment: Yeah. My real code is in React. I just wrote this in vanilla javascript , html and css for sake of simplicity. Yes, I prefer, React solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scrollIntoView by targeting the id of whatever the next slide is and have a simple state to keep track of the current id.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(1)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (current === 6) setCurrent(1)
    document.querySelector(`#slide-${current > 5?1:current}`).scrollIntoView();
  }, [current])
  return (
    <div className="slider">
      <button onClick={() => {
          setCurrent(cur=>cur+1)
        }}>Next</button>
      <div className="slides">
        <div id="slide-1">
          1
        </div>
        <div id="slide-2">
          2
        </div>
        <div id="slide-3">
          3
        </div>
        <div id="slide-4">
          4
        </div>
        <div id="slide-5">
          5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<div><App /></div>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  
  
  
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  
  /*
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  */
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
.slides > div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.slides > div:target {
/*   transform: scale(0.8); */
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider > a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}
.slider > a:active {
  top: 1px;
}
.slider > a:focus {
  background: #000;
}

/* Don't need button navigation */
@supports (scroll-snap-type) {
  .slider > a {
    display: none;
  }
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74ABE2, #5563DE);
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: If I integrate this as a part of page then when I click on navbar item the whole page is getting scrolled downwards and then the scroll snap moves.